# Self-Signed UWP Apps in Windows 10 S

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I've got a UWP developed that runs just fine on Windows 10 for desktops and phones. Because the app isn't in the Windows Store, I've got it configured to be self-signed, and that seems to work just fine. However, we now need to support Windows 10 S.

I can install the app just fine in 10 S, but it fails to open and the event log gives me the following error:

> Activation of the app {App name} for the Windows.Launch contract was
>   blocked with error 0x80073CFC because of an issue with application
>   binary {App name}. This could be because the binary is unsigned,
>   contains an untrusted signature, or has been corrupted or tampered
>   with. Reinstall the application to fix this issue.

I think this has to do with Microsoft wanting all apps installed on Win 10 S to come from the Windows store. Does anyone know of a way to get around this (other than upgrading the laptop to a full version of Windows 10)?

Comment: Unless there's a developer setting for S, the simplest fix would be to pay for a code signing cert.

Comment: @DaveS it won't work for Windows 10 S. There is no way to fix that. This is intended way for things to work.

Comment: You're right - I was just thinking about the cert, not that the download method must be from the Windows Store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sideloading of self-signed apps on Windows 10S is not supported.

To test your app for the Win10 S configuration before releasing it via Windows Store, please follow [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s).